# Build on Google App Engine flexible environment is failing

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my first project to Google App Engine but getting some kind of build error.

The error messages are very obtuse though so I can't work out whether this is my fault or not.

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
env_variables:
    BUCKET: 'xyz'
    MONGODB_URI: 'mongodb://xyz'
```

The error messages in the logs:

```
72681 silly finalize /app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/lodash.padstart/node_modules/lodash._baseslice
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --unsafe-perm ||   ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then       cat npm-debug.log;     fi) && false)' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:d03a22d793930dbfedfa52e0975340a76fd921af28252172e82feef09b9a0a37" failed: exit status 1
72682 silly finalize /app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge
```

If someone could at least pinpoint the module or section that is causing this build to fail that would at least point me in the right direction. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the problem is stemming from `npm install` during the image build. Have you verified `npm install` works locally?

Comment: Yes, `npm install` works locally. However I'm on Windows so it could be that it fails on Linux. Either way, how can I see which package failed to install?

Comment: It looks like the problem was with the package.json `"postinstall": "bower install"`. I've deployed the app without that line and it now seems to work.

Comment: However all my `bower_components` still seem to be available - does gcloud deploy all files in a project, even when in a .gitignore?

Comment: Yes it will deploy all files because it doesn't use git at all. However it is a docker build so a .dockerignore file would probably work. Do you not want the bower components there?